# JPA optimize query performance

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, jpa

I have a query in my Spring application which joins a table and a view. The relation between the two is 1-0..1 and the selection happens on the first table.

```
select *
from a
left join b on a.id = b.id
```

I'm currently executing my query like this:

```
List<Record> list = em.createNativeQuery(query, Record.class)
    .setFirstResult(offset)
    .setMaxResults(limit)
    .getResultList();
```

Which I guess translates to:

```
select *
from a
left join b on a.id = b.id
where a.x = 1234
offset 100000
limit 1000
```

However, this is faster:

```
with t as (
    select *
    from a
    where x = 1234
    offset 100000
    limit 1000
)
select *
from t
left join b on t.id = b.id
```

Should I get rid of `setFirstResult` and `getMaxResults`, and construct the query myself? Or are there other options?

Thanks

Comment: *"Which I guess translates to"* - Did you check that? I doubt that JPA implementations add `OFFSET .. LIMIT` to native queries. Your alternative query is not the same as your original.

Comment: It does: `select current_query from pg_stat_activity` gives me `select ... where ... limit $1 offset $2`

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. What implementation?

Comment: Hibernate, via spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 1.2.4.RELEASE

Comment: native query option is exactly for you to construct the query yourself; using maxResults/firstResult on them makes little sense